# Javascript, how to load, draw and loop 120 frames?

Tags: javascript, animation, drawing, loading

I'm trying to load 120 images into an array:

```
var bgframes = [];
for(i=0; i<119; i++)
{
 var frameX = new Image();
 if (i>99)
 {
  frameX.src = 'src/bg/background_00'+i+'.jpg';
  bgframes.push(frameX);
 }
 else if (i>9)
 {
  frameX.src = 'src/bg/background_000'+i+'.jpg';
  bgframes.push(frameX);
 }
 else
 {
  frameX.src = 'src/bg/background_0000'+i+'.jpg';
  bgframes.push(frameX);
 }
}
```

Then trying to loop through them, drawing them on a canvas using:

```
var bgf=0;
setInterval(drawFrame,1000/60);
function drawFrame()
{
  if (bgf>119){bgf=0;}
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,myCanvas.width,myCanvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(bgframes[bgf],0,0);
  bgf++;
}
```

Testing this, the animation will play once and then I will get: 
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'

Answer (score 2):

your for loop only populate 119 images (0 to 118 ... 119 is NOT less than 119)

but your drawFrame function loops from 0 to 119

change the for loop to

```
for(i=0; i<120; i++)
```

I'd also recommend changing the drawFrame code as follows

```
function drawFrame() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,myCanvas.width,myCanvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(bgframes[bgf],0,0);
  bgf = (bgf + 1) % bgframes.length; // if bgframes length changes, no need to change the code here as well
}
```

may I also suggest using requestAnimationFrame like this

```
var bgf=0;

function drawFrame() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,myCanvas.width,myCanvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(bgframes[bgf],0,0);
    bgf = (bgf + 1) % bgframes.length;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
```

requestAnimationFrame usually runs at 60/second anyway